# I want to set a "for" counter for each array in only one "for" declaration, rather than create two "for" declarations. How can I make it possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

**// Declared Arrays**

```
const aList3 = ["frog", "hippo", "snake", "owl", "sheep"];
const aList4 = ["eagle", "bee", "crab", "hippo", "iguana"];
```

**// Declaring the Function**

```
function isEqual(animals, animals2) {
```

**// Declaring a Counter for Each Array**

```
    for (let j = 0, k = 0; j < animals.length, k < animals2.length; j++, k++) {
```

**// Declaring the Condition**

```
        if (animals[j] === animals2[k]) {
            return "You finded this common animals: " + animals[j];
        }
    }
    return "You didn't find any common animal";
}
```

**// Calling the Function**

```
const sameAnimal3 = isEqual(aList3, aList4);
console.log(sameAnimal3);
```

**Some solution is use the same `for` counter, but for me doesn't work. I want it to work no matter of the index position or the length**

```
for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    if (animals[i] === animals2[i]) {
        return "You finded this common animals: " + animals[i];
    }
    return "You didn't find any common animal";
}
```

Comment: just get rid of k, as k is exactly the same as j (assuming both arrays are the same length, which you can check prior to the loop).

Comment: Why not simply use filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by allowing both arrays to use the same `for` counter:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
    if (animals[i] === animals2[i]) {
        return "You finded this common animals: " + animals[i];
    }
    return "You didn't find any common animal";
}
```

But you have to be careful in a scenario where:

1. The arrays have different lengths
2. The common animal is not in the same index.

---

To properly solve this, use a `dictionary` to keep track of *seen* animals:

```js
// Dictionary to keep track of seen animals.
const seen = {}

for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {

    // Check both array's current index if animal is seen already.
    if(seen[animals[i]] || seen[animals2[i]]) {

        // If seen already, take which animal is found between the two array.
        const foundAnimal = seen[animals[i]] ? animals[i] : animals2[i]
        
        return "You finded this common animals: " + foundAnimal;
    } else {

        // If neither animals are seen before, add to the seen dictionary for future reference.
        seen[animals[i]] = true;
        seen[animals2[i]] = true;
    }
}

// You have not seen any animals twice.
return "You didn't find any common animal";
```

Comment: using a dictionary looks promising, thanks